# battle tested jquery / javascript drop down menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, cascadingdropdown

Drop Down menus are a common and almost ubiquitous UI element, and yet, I find it really hard to "pick one".  before heading down the long road of rolling and "battle testing" my own, I'd like to put it out there and find out what others are using.

What are the most popular solutions for jquery, or javascript dropdown menus ?

Should be, lightweight, easy to customise and properly cross browser compatible, and at least function appropriately down to IE8.

Ones I've tried and used in the past with the best experience that meet this criteria  inlcude :

- Super fish - http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/
- Dynamic Drive Smooth Menu http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddsmoothmenu.htm

To Clarify:  looking specifically for multilevel drop down menus similar to the examples above.  I'm also open to "avoid these they're sh*t"  type answers if you feel so inclined.

PS: please avoid adding 5 from one of the 500 drop down menu articles that appear when first searching on google, I'd like to know about what YOU"RE using, what dropdown menus YOU love and hate.

Comment: I always do my own menus, and once you get the hang of it creating a dropdown menu is a matter of minutes, and really not that hard.

Comment: I've built my own a few times as well, and while I'm not adverse to that at all, I'm curious to see what the general consensus is.  I suppose in a way I'm wanting to take a little bit of a pole,  and I'm also looking for a quick default solution.  I dont like to re invent the wheel, and also don't want to take the roll your own approach out of  ignorance if there are solid solutions available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a fair amount of research and messing about, quite honestly I'm fairly disappointed with the options in this area there are a couple options but as commented above rolling my own seems to be the best way forward.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this may be this can give you what you want

http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

Comment: not really what I'm after,  think horizontal / vertical multi level menus - along the lines of the examples I've added above.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have used SuperFish, in it's standard form, it's not too pretty but with quite a bit of adjustments I find it can look quite nice.

Then using something like this: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations

Demo: http://snook.ca/technical/jquery-bg/

Can make them look very cool!

Comment: I used superfish for ages, but really hated  - back before I was prepared to dig into it - and this will sound lame, - but really  really hated the lack of closing animation.  Otherwise pretty cool.

Comment: I think, for me, it was always the "basicness" of it that got me, always felt a bit like "my first menu" - That said, I can't complain as it's free, and so far, been very robust!

Comment: agreed  - certainly robust and one of the most stable.